# Prevent real server IP exposure

Tags: php, security, cloudflare

I'm hosting a couple of sites for my friends, which they can edit using SFTP. But I recently stumbled upon something quite alarming.

Using: `<? echo $realIP = file_get_contents("http://ipecho.net/plain"); ?>`

They are able to get the real IP of the server. I'm using CloudFlare to "mask" the IP from the outside, so that's quite safe. I know that I can use a VPN for this, but that a quite expensive option. Is there any way to avoid, them using this certain methodes to gain the real server IP?

Comment: I don't understand. You're worried about your friends figuring out what IP address your host has? Why? I don't think this should be "alarming" at all.

Comment: If you allow them to run code on your machine, there is not much you can do (a VPN won't help). Why are you concerned about this?

Comment: No you cannot.  You can't have a 2 way mask, impossible.  You can spoof traffic one way but that is it, 2 ways is impossible.  Real IP's can not be spoofed 2 ways because the server and client have to communicate to send any data back and forth, if IP's were masked both ways, you would not be able to communicate to the server or client because each system would not no where to send the data.  Why are you trying to hide the server IP from people you have granted FTP access to?

Comment: What does `file_get_contents` have to do with 146.255.36.1 ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, it's clear now. The reason I want to hide it, is because I'm hosting these websites by myself on my home network. But thats certainly a risk I have to take. For the record: I do trust them, but you never know who has access to their FTP account.

Comment: Turn off `allow_url_fopen` then they won't be able to open remote urls using the stream wrappers, like `fopen`. and `file_get_contents`  Additionally if your worried about this `but you never know who has access to their FTP account` then the other issues is sort of small potatoes.  I would also turn off `shell_exec`, `exec`, `eval`, `popen` and a few other choice functions.  There is a `disabled` functions setting in the PHP ini file.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Excellent! That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Kool, that is like step one in securing a server that works like shared hosting.  There may be other ways to get the IP though, that was why I said to turn of `exec` because they could execute linux commands to get the ip.  You can also set their user accounts in a way that they can sFTP, but have no shell access to run commands.  For example `usermod -s /sbin/nologin myuser`  See this topic on [Unix.Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55106/disable-user-shell-for-security-reasons)

Comment: And if they don't have FTP, but only access to the file by using a shared Cloudservice or something. Is disabling ```exec``` still necessary than?

Comment: It depends on the privileges their user has, but that is starting to get on the edge of what  I know, I only have a small knowlage about sever security because we have an outside contractor that manages our security.  So I know just enough to get by.  I'm Primarily a PHP developer, although I do have other responsibilities, that touch on some of these things.

Comment: If it was me, I would set up a testing account with similar access as they have and then use that to see what can and can't be done and how to prevent it without breaking to much.  It never hurts to test, test and then test again.  I would also do some research on common shared hosting settings etc...  Like this post http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/web-hosting-security-best-practices/

Comment: I'll do that! Thanks for the help, your answer absolutely solved my problem.

Comment: I will write up an answer then,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just generally secure the server in a way that is similar to typical shared hosting accounts.

While this is on the edge of what I know, I am by no means an expert on server security I do know a few things I have ran into over the years.

- disable using stream file wrappers for remote files. This is controlled by the `allow_url_fopen` setting in PHP, and disables opening remote files using `fopen`, `file_get_contents` and their like.
- disable some of the more dangerous PHP functions these include but are not limited to `shell_exec`, `exec`, `eval`, `popen`.  These likewise can be disabled in the PHP ini file by adding them to the `disabled_functions` list.
- remove shell access for the users.  They will still be able to authenticate for sFTP, for file transfers.  But they will not be able to login via SSH through something like putty you can modify the users like this `usermod -s /sbin/nologin myuser`  for more details see this post on [Unix.StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55106/disable-user-shell-for-security-reasons)
- setup a test account with the same access your clients (people you provide hosting for) have and test what works and what doesn't.  This will give you a bit of an idea what they can and cant do, and it gives you a place to test some configuration changes before applying them globally.

I am sure there are many more things you can do, and I can't really go into a whole article on server security. As I said I am by no means an authority on the subject.  So the last thing I would say is do as much research as you can and see what others are doing for shared hosting servers as this is basically what you have.

I did find this Post on 14 best practices on server security.

http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/web-hosting-security-best-practices/

This just gives a high level overview of some of the concerns and doesn't really get to overly technical.

This is a pretty big topic, with many pitfalls, but I hope my limited knowledge at least gets you started down the road of securing your server. And remember, it's your server you get to say what the policies are on it.

That said it is very important to communicate with your users about any policy changes.  They have pretty much had free reign up to this point.  But if you explain to them that it's in their interest because it not only protects the server but also protects their data, it may go over a bit easier.  They do have a right to know, and you do have an obligation to tell them.  This way they can make any necessary changes to their code.  But again, it is your server ultimately and it's your responsibility to make it as secure as you can.

Good Luck!